# Should trigonometric functions be cached?

Tags: java, caching, compiler-optimization, jit

How extensive are functions like `Math.sin()`, `Math.cos()` etc.? 
Does the compiler optimise the code if you call the method with the same arguments multiple times in a row? If not, at how many calls of these methods should you start caching the result in a variable?

Comment: You should let JIT worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

The trigonometric functions are usually implemented as Taylor expansions. They are fast. You can write your own and compare.

```
public class Main{
    private static double factorial(double n) {
        if (n <= 1) // base case
            return 1;
        else
            return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
    private static double sin(int n) {
        int PRECISION = 10;
        double rad = n*1./180.*Math.PI;
        double sum = rad;
        for (int i = 1; i <= PRECISION; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                sum += Math.pow(rad, 2*i+1) / factorial(2 * i + 1);
            else
                sum -= Math.pow(rad, 2*i+1) / factorial(2 * i + 1);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(sin(180));
        System.out.println(Math.sin(Math.PI));

        System.out.println(sin(90));
        System.out.println(Math.sin(Math.PI/2));

        System.out.println(sin(200));
        System.out.println(Math.sin(200*2*Math.PI/360));
    }
}
```

Surely you can cache the values but these methods are likely to be already optimized.

Comment: You can keep a running variable for the factorial element, which will save avoid an O(n^2) issue (factorial itself is O(n) as written). After that is done, sin & cos can be implemented O(n) where n is precision.

Answer (score 1):

As with all performance questions, you should write a benchmark and find out for yourself, since the answer will depend on your JVM, OS, and hardware. It's probably safe to say that Math.sin/cos will take a few hundred nanoseconds on modern PC and server hardware - more than loading something from main memory - so your best bet to maximize performance is to cache whenever possible. But always measure before and after making changes.